# Adding textboxes over the panel height

Tags: c#

So I need to add textboxes to a panel with a click of a button. Every click adds one textbox under the last one and so on. But when it goes over the panel height it suddenly makes bigger space between the texboxes even though the int is still the same.
Here's my code so far.

```
List<TextBox> textboxes = new List<TextBox>();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbY += 30;
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Left = 3;
    tb.Top = tbY;
    tb.Font = new Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
    tb.Size = new Size(325, 25);
    tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    button1.Top = tbY;
    panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
    textboxes.Add(tb);
    ScrollToBottom(panel1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Top` of a `Control` is calculated relative to the scroll position of its `Parent`.

You are always scrolling to the bottom of your `Panel`, so you need to set it like this, taking the curent scroll position into account:

```
tb.Top = tbY + panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y;
```

Note that the `AutoScrollPosition.Y` is **negative** when you have scrolled **downward**, so we need to add it!

Answer (score 0):

You might as well use a flowLayoutPanel for this purpose. Use the following properties on your flowLayoutPanel and it'll work as you intend. (without having to do the manual calculation)

```
        List<TextBox> textboxes = new List<TextBox>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
            flowLayoutPanel1.WrapContents = false;
            flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


           TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Left = 3;          
            tb.Font = new Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            tb.Size = new Size(325, 25);
            tb.Text = tb.Top.ToString();            
            tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;           
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(tb);
            textboxes.Add(tb);

        }
```